# How to download and run a .exe file c#

Tags: c#, download, exe, execution

Before you flag this as a duplicate, yes there are questions just like this, i've looked at all of them and still couldn't get this working. I'm trying to code in a feature that downloads and runs a .exe file but it doesn't download, run or do anything. I even removed the try catches to find an error or error codes but I have non, so I have no idea where i'm going wrong, here is my code for it

```
public test_Configuration()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/files/example.exe");
    string filename = @"C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\example.exe";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if(File.Exists(filename))
            {
                File.Delete(filename);
            }
            else
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.DownloadDataAsync(uri, filename);
                wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
                wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }      
    }
    private void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
    }
    private void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Error == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Download complete!, running exe", "Completed!");
            Process.Start(filename);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to download exe, please check your connection", "Download failed!");
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change [`DownloadDataAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144191(v=vs.110).aspx) to [`DownloadFileAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
wc.DownloadFileAsync(uri, filename);
```

Comment: Thanks! didn't think it'd be such an easy fix

Answer (score 0):

This code helped me out quite a bit with updating a file, so I thought I would show my twist in the hopes that someone else out there has a similar requirement as me.

I needed this code to do the following when a button was clicked:

1. Grab a file from a sever and store it locally in AppData\Temp.
2. Keep my user up-to-date of install progress (an installer is downloaded).
3. If successfully downloaded (note the removal of the else after deleting old file check), launch "daInstaller.exe", whilst terminating the current running program.
4. And if said file already exist (i.e. the old "daIstaller.exe"), delete prior to copying new file to AppData\Temp.

Don't forget to keep the file names the same, else you'll be leaving more trash in that AppData\Temp folder.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/files/example.exe");
        filename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Temp/example.exe");

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                File.Delete(filename);
            }

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(uri, filename);
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

    }

    private void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
    }
    private void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            Process.Start(filename);
            Close();
            Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to download exe, please check your connection", "Download failed!");
        }
    }
```