# C# Download Files from github

Tags: c#

I had created a program that auto update itself,by downloading newer version from github. But the program keeps downloading the source html of the webpage and not the program. The link I had used is https://github.com/PoH98/MyBot.Supporter/raw/master/MyBot.Supporter.Main.exe and suppose all the browsers will download the exe. But when I using WebClient for download, it downloaded https://github.com/PoH98/MyBot.Supporter/blob/master/MyBot.Supporter.Main.exe source HTML code! My codes are here:

```
WebClient wc = new Webclient();
wc.Downloadfile("https://github.com/PoH98/MyBot.Supporter/raw/master/MyBot.Supporter.Main.exe","Update");
File.Delete("MyBot.Supporter.Main.exe");
File.Move("Update","MyBot.Supporter.Main.exe");
```

Am I doing any wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download and run a .exe file c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684243/how-to-download-and-run-a-exe-file-c-sharp)

Comment: just tried your code, the file download perfectly, maybe your internet is redirecting you?

Comment: Tried different host and fixed the problem. Maybe is my internet redirecting. But since some or my user still happens sometimes, I had switched to other server host. Can't really identify the problem....